# What were the reasons for bounty removal on this question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, bounty

Someone started a bounty on a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35202239/jacoco-coverage-report-issues) yesterday. So, I have answered that question but today I see that the bounty is removed from the question and its showing below message in [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/35202239/revisions):

> Notice removed Authoritative reference needed by "Some Moderator"

What's the reason to remove this bounty?

Comment: Maybe the user asked for the bounty to be removed and Cody obliged? [The bounty was up for only three hours](https://cl.ly/abd644/Image%2525202019-02-19%252520at%25252011.44.29%252520AM.png).

Comment: @yivi Is that question solved the problem?

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand. I was only speculating with my comment anyway.

Comment: @yivi wouldn't it be odd to remove a bounty and reinstate the rep if it was already put to use? (the answer was posted after the bounty was posted)

Comment: @Tim Probably. But the only other reason I can think of for bounty removal is for closing a question or voting fraud, and those do not seem to be the case here, as far as I can see. I'm sure Cody will enlighten us all when he sees this.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

First of all sorry for the confusion.

While putting bounty I had forgotten to ***specify*** my problem in "Optional Description".
So I did custom mod flag, asking to add the optional description. One of mod helped me there and he reverted my bounty point because even a mod can't add description later after bounty is put already.

So only possible way was to revert the bounty back to my rep bag and I was supposed to put bounty again which I didn't do.

With this post, I just want to assure you that nothing unfair happened with you from the community. It was me who wanted to update the description and that too after your post only it came into my mind since your answer post was not something I was looking for.

Hope that cleared your doubt.

Also I put the bounty again, you can check that.

Comment: As I understood it the moderator only removed the bounty to allow you to reinstate it with a different description. Bounties can usually not be cancelled and in this specific case, you even got an additional answer due to the bounty. Removing it afterwards sounds very much like taking the benefits but not paying for it which is problematic. I'm almost sure that the mod would have never cancelled your bounty if you told them that you wouldn't add it again.

Comment: @BDL I understand the problem here. However if you look at the other way, the answer probably would have never received the bounty because of the reason I mentioned already in my post.

Comment: Please check again with the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty). It is impossible for you to not award a bounty. Either you do it manually after the bounty has ended, or it is automatically awarded to the highest ranked answer (with at least +2). The answer could have easily received at least 50% of the bounty. In either way, the reputation is removed from your account.

Comment: Problem is, even if the LittlNaruto reposted the bounty, user5377037 would never get it, right? The answer would have been posted **before** the bounty.

Comment: @yivi For that the answer post has to have at least one upvote IIRC

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto In seven days? A question with 100 rep bounty? Easy peasy.

Comment: Ok Let's not extend this anymore. I'll put the bounty again with the optional description. :)

Comment: @user5377037 may want to delete their answer and post it again, if they want a chance to get that bounty (or part of it), unless I misremember bounty rules.

Comment: The bounty was removed on the premise that you would reapply it, not doing so (in my world) seems dishonest and rather bad taste. And could potentially lead to mods not doing you this kind of favours again even if you really do intend to keep your end.

Comment: @Epodax You have a valid point. Check my edit.

Comment: @user5377037 That's entirely **too** reasonable. We can't accept that. Please work a bit more in being outraged. /s

Comment: After @yivi 's comment I un-accept the answer. because there is nothing stated about the bounty will be refundable in the [bounty help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty).

Comment: @user53 what do you mean by "refundable" ?

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto read the [bounty help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty) "A bounty is a special reputation award given to answers. It is funded by the personal reputation of the user who offers it, and is **non-refundable**."

Comment: @user53 Yeah so what is wrong here ? I already put the bounty again, didn't I ? I think we can assume it was an exception case. And we had to handle it manually ? And that's what we did.

Comment: @user5377037 in a normal case, the bounty is non-refundable after 7 days with no satisfying answers... *unless* a mod cancel the bounty (usually done on questions that need to be closed but cannot due to the bounty), which will refund the rep back to the OP.

Comment: Related: [Editing bounty messages, is it finally time for a little “Love”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/324104/232439)

Comment: Yes, I refunded the bounty with the expectation that you would reinstate it. It is a very hackish workaround for the inability to modify bounty messages. I probably wouldn't have done it if the bounty had been active for several days, but it had only been active for a few hours. The amount of free publicity you were getting was minimal, and it did appear to be an honest mistake.

Comment: @Cody Thanks for helping me out. One more reason was I caught up in some work @ office. So almost had forgotten about it. Yeah sure I made mistake. But I think it's all good now.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 Manually, yes. But since LittleNaruto already said they are not going to award it themselves, I was referring to automatically awarded bounties (and in those cases, the answer has to be posted _after_ the bounty starts, unless I'm wrong).

Comment: @yivi Surprisingly, you're right. I didn't expect it to work that way.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 To me, it's certainly **not** suprising to be right. ;)